# How to send a jsoup Elements object between activities

Tags: android, jsoup

after parsing some information from a website using Jsoup, I would need to pass it from the main Activity to another. This information comes in an 'Elements' object.

I have read that, if I want to do that with a class I have created, I would need to implement Parcelable or Serializable. But I do not know if the Elements class from Jsoup has those characteristics.

Maybe there is a better way to do that than using Parcelable or Serializable, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to send it as string with intent

Comment: But I don't know how many elements are inside that Elements object for tagging each one of them with a different name and then make the putExtra or putExtras thing

Answer (score 0):

> But I do not know if the [Elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) class from Jsoup has those
>   characteristics.

Read JavaDoc for such information

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html

It is usually better to separate from 3rd part library like Jsoup and use somethink else locally. So extract important infrormation from Elements like text, links etc and pass it to your custom object for further processing. Your custom object may implement any interface.

---